# Interstitial don't appear.

Tags: ios, objective-c, interstitial

I use this code for add interstitial:

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                           nil];



    gadinter = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    gadinter.delegate = self;
    gadinter.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-8360827428091030/4165686904";

    [gadinter loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {

    [gadinter presentFromRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
}
```

and i'm getting this :

`2015-02-09 18:57:12.636 iStrobe[5951:1824030] <Google> Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready.
2015-02-09 18:57:13.801 iStrobe[5951:1824030] <Google> No UIViewController supplied to the ad. Cannot continue.`

Any ideea why ? In others app it works.

Comment: What is your rootViewControlelr? Is it a `UINavigationController`, or `UITabBarController`, or `UIViewController`?

Comment: Could you add a `NSLog(%"%@", self.window.rootViewController)` in front of the `[gadinter presentFromRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController]` and see what the value is? Could it be `nil`?

Comment: As I am looking through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial). It seems that they put the ad init code in `viewDidLoad`. There may be a chance that your rootViewController is not ready when this `- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial` get called.

Comment: thanks @YuchenZhong , i added in viewDidLoad and now it's ok.

Comment: then great, you can write your own answer if you have figure this out so that it will be helpful to other in the future..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my viewController i added it this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                           nil];



    gadinter = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    gadinter.delegate = self;
    gadinter.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-8360827428091030/4165686904";

    [gadinter loadRequest:request];

}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [gadinter presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason interstitialDidReceiveAd never executes. I can manually show the ad if I wait enough time though so everything else is configured correctly, it's just that the delegate is not executing.